# Unable to link my ESP32-base firmware due to missing `bootloader__40m.elf` after libs upgrades

Tags: arduino, linker, espressif-idf

After an upgrade of the libs, I am no longer able to link the firmware as I get this error:

> *** [.pio/build/nano/bootloader.bin] Source `/Users/stephanedeluca/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/bin/bootloader__40m.elf' not found, needed by target` .pio/build/nano/bootloader.bin'.

The libs have been upgraded like so

```
[env]
platform = espressif32
;@ ~3.5.0
board = esp-wrover-kit
;board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
platform_packages =
    framework-arduinoespressif32
    ;3.20007.0 << new version
    ;@3.10006.210326
    tool-esptoolpy
    ;@1.40201.0 << new version
    ;@1.30100.210531
    toolchain-xtensa32
    ;@2.50200.97 << stick to the same version
    ;@2.50200.97
```

Weird enough, is that on my colleague PC, he does not have any issue and manages to link the firmware.

Note: I am working on a MacBook

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution.

As I didn't find any logical solution, I did:
• close `vscode`;
• remove `.pio` folder from the project;
• remove `.platformio` folder from /users/;

Then I reopened the project so that vscode could reinstall platformio and the libs.

And voilà!